# Upload a csv file to Rshiny, then reuse that dataframe again (within multiple renderTable instructions) instead of uploading it again each time

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to upload a csv into Shiny then, reuse it in different outputs but not have to read it in over again each time. Can the data be stored to be used again. Please see below my example. In the "contents2" server section, I know I can read in the data again to get the results but is there a more efficient way to reuse that dataframe instead.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      
      tableOutput("contents"),
      tableOutput("contents2")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    
    file <- input$file1
    req(file)
    df <- read.csv(file$datapath ) 
    
    df[1:10,]
    
  })
  
  output$contents2 <- renderTable({

    # file <- input$file1 # code i can use but would rather not repeat
    # req(file) # code i can use but would rather not repeat
    # df <- read.csv(file$datapath ) # code i can use but would rather not repeat
    
    df[ (nrow(df)-10):nrow(df), ]
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a `reactive` object which is used to share data

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents"),
      tableOutput("contents2")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    read.csv(input$file1$datapath) 
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    data()[1:10,]
  })
  
  output$contents2 <- renderTable({
    nr <- nrow(data())  
    data()[ (nr-10):nr, ]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]